# SQL: Generating a field based on a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (for the sake of the exercise let's call it Persons)
[image]

I am trying to create a query that will generate the CrDRN number.

The `CrDRN column` should contain the DRN number of the last record that has a `VoucherType = 80`

In this instance the CrDRN column would have the values 1 1 1 5 5

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The CrDRN column should contain the DRN number of the last record that
>   has a VoucherType = 80

Another way of saying that would be to get the max value of `DRN` where `DRN` is less than or equal to the current `DRN` and where `VoucherType` is `80`.

You can formulate just that in a subquery that returns `CrDRN`.

```
select T1.DRN,
       T1.VoucherType,
       (
       select max(T2.DRN)
       from T as T2
       where T2.DRN <= T1.DRN and
             T2.VoucherType = 80
       ) as CrDRN
from T as T1
```

Comment: I apologise for the stupid question, I have little to no experience with SQL short of Insert, Update and Delete.

Comment: No worries. Your attempted query look like you have written it for MySQL. Using that and fixing the typos and using `top(1)` instead of `limit` would also work.